# EXCEPTION_THROWN|[EXTERNAL]|System.VisualforceException: Update access denied for Console_Master__c, controller action methods may not execute

Tags: issue, spring21

I am facing an error for Guest Users. When I click on the Del button of the bellow page it will show the "EXCEPTION_THROWN|[EXTERNAL]|System.VisualforceException: Update access denied for Console_Master__c, controller action methods may not execute.
"error in Debug Log. Even not showing the first line Debug on this method. I used Without Sharing In my Class given all possible permission and Sharing settings. It is working fine before Spring 21 release.
Please help me to resolve this issue ASAP.
[image: VF Code Del method is not working]
[image: Del method used on the action of Vf page]
[image: VFpage]

Thanks

Namrata

Comment: Is your code running under a User with a public site guest license?

Comment: Yes user is  with a public site guest license and del action is working for other pages not only working for this

Comment: Removing access for Guest User with Spring 21 release was an intended change. 
Edit,Delete,Modify All,View All -guest user object permissions are removed with the Spring ’21 release.See https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_guest_policies_timelines.htm&type=5 for more details. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour as of Spring '21 release for Guest Users. The following guest user object permissions are removed with the Spring ’21 release and this is a signal that Salesforce are taking on a serious effort to block free/low paid licenses from powerful access, especially site users on external sites.

- Edit
- Delete
- Modify All
- View All

I can recommend two things:

1. Review your object access/operations for the current Guest User.
2. Insert ops are still possible so you can try a staging object with the Site data and then map it to the SObject that is blocked today from being updated. Mapping from staging to SObject would take place under a full license user / system admin.